# Symfony twig how to add class to a form row

Tags: symfony, twig, symfony-forms

I am building a project in Symfony 2.3 using Twig. I want to add a class to the form row block. I am using a form theme file which contains:

```
{% block form_row %}
    <div class="form-row">
        {{ form_label(form) }}
        {{ form_widget(form) }}
        {{ form_errors(form) }}
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

Now some of my form rows I want to add an extra class `form-row-split`. I can't figure out how to do this properly. The way I have it almost-working is:

```
{% block form_row %}
    {% set attr = attr|merge({'class': 'form-row' ~ (attr.class is defined ? ' ' ~ attr.class : '') ~ (errors|length > 0 ? ' error' : '')} ) %}
    <div {{ block('widget_container_attributes') }}>
        {{ form_label(form) }}
        {{ form_widget(form) }}
        {{ form_errors(form) }}
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

(Note, I've left the `error` class logic in there too as that needs to stay).
Then in the form builder:

```
$builder
        ->add('first_name', 'text', array(
            'attr' => array(
                'class' => 'form-row-split'
            )
        ));
```

This almost works but it adds this class everywhere and also adds the widget id to the row!

```
<div id="myform_first_name" class="form-row form-row-split">
    <label for="myform_first_name">First name</label>
    <input id="myform_first_name" class="form-row-split" type="text" name="myform[first_name]">
</div>
```

I can think of a few potential solutions but none of them are pretty or straight forward. Surely there must be a simple way of doing this?

Comment: Why not implement `div.form-row-split` or `label.form-row-split` or `input.form-row-split` instead of a simple `form-row-split` in your css file, instead of finding a hack in the form generation?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

There is a fairly simple solution to this problem actually. I just needed a form type extension to extend the base form type to allow an extra available option: http://symfony.com/doc/2.3/cookbook/form/create_form_type_extension.html

Following through the example in the docs, I created a new form type extension:

```
// src/Acme/FrontendBundle/Form/Extension/FormTypeExtension.php

namespace Acme\FrontendBundle\Form\Extension;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractTypeExtension;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormView;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;

/**
 * Class FormTypeExtension
 * @package Acme\FrontendBundle\Form\Extension
 */
class FormTypeExtension extends AbstractTypeExtension
{
    /**
     * Extends the form type which all other types extend
     *
     * @return string The name of the type being extended
     */
    public function getExtendedType()
    {
        return 'form';
    }

    /**
     * Add the extra row_attr option
     *
     * @param OptionsResolverInterface $resolver
     */
    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'row_attr' => array()
        ));
    }

    /**
     * Pass the set row_attr options to the view
     *
     * @param FormView $view
     * @param FormInterface $form
     * @param array $options
     */
    public function buildView(FormView $view, FormInterface $form, array $options)
    {
        $view->vars['row_attr'] = $options['row_attr'];
    }
}
```

Then I registered the service in my bundle...

```
<!-- Form row attributes form extension -->
<service id="acme.form_type_extension" class="Acme\FrontendBundle\Form\Extension\FormTypeExtension">
    <tag name="form.type_extension" alias="form" />
</service>
```

Since every widget extends the base form type this then allows me to pass this new `row_attr` option through on any field, eg:

```
$builder
    ->add('first_name', 'text', array(
        'row_attr' => array(
            'class' => 'form-row-split'
        )
    ));
```

Then the twig overrides to make use of the new `row_attr` option:

```
{% block form_row %}
    <div {{ block('form_row_attributes') }}>
        {{ form_label(form) }}
        {{ form_widget(form) }}
        {{ form_errors(form) }}
    </div>
{% endblock form_row %}

{% block form_row_attributes %}
    {% spaceless %}
        {% for attrname, attrvalue in row_attr %}{{ attrname }}="{{ attrvalue }}" {% endfor %}
    {% endspaceless %}
{% endblock form_row_attributes %}
```

And it's done!

(For completeness, my full twig override still merges in the `form-row` and `error` classes in like so:

```
{% set row_attr = row_attr|merge({'class': 'form-row' ~ (row_attr.class is defined ? ' ' ~ row_attr.class : '') ~ (errors|length > 0 ? ' error' : '')} ) %}
```

.. but thats not really necessary for answering my own question :P )

Comment: Yes! Thanks @lopsided this was super helpful to me right now, excellent answer (and question) :)

Comment: [Up to date link for form type extension doc](http://symfony.com/doc/master/form/create_form_type_extension.html)

Comment: Do you know how to make this work easily with RepeatedType forms ?

Answer (score 23):

[Docs](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html#form-theming) say: you always able to pass attr to rendered element:

```
{{ form_start(form, {'attr': {'class': 'your-class'}} ) }}
    {{ form_label(form, {'attr': {'class': 'your-class'}}) }}
    {{ form_widget(form, {'attr': {'class': 'your-class'}}) }}
    {{ form_errors(form, {'attr': {'class': 'your-class'}}) }}
{{ form_end(form) }}
```

Comment: This only allows you to pass `attr` to the form, label, widget, errors, NOT the row. In fact if you look at the original theme file (`form_div_layout.html.twig`) you can see that in the `form_row` block, the surrounding `<div>` will never inject any passed vars... hence my question of how to do this. Thanks for your suggestion though.

Comment: @lopsided, you are right, then there is only one option, - to override form_row, to your need in your template.

Comment: Yeah I have got the `form_row` override, but I need half of the rows to use one version and the other half to use the other version with the extra `form-row-split` class. Except they all use the same `form_row` override block - so I need to be able to pass something into this override block somehow...

Answer (score 8):

Below is a clone of answer by @lopsided but with changes reflecting latest Symfony structure changes (v. 2.7+):

---

There is a fairly simple solution to this problem actually. I just needed a form type extension to extend the base form type to allow an extra available option: http://symfony.com/doc/master/form/create_form_type_extension.html

Following through the example in the docs, I created a new form type extension:

```
// src/Acme/FrontendBundle/Form/Extension/FormTypeExtension.php

namespace Acme\FrontendBundle\Form\Extension;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractTypeExtension;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormView;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\FormType;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;

/**
 * Class FormTypeExtension
 * @package Acme\FrontendBundle\Form\Extension
 */
class FormTypeExtension extends AbstractTypeExtension
{
    /**
     * Extends the form type which all other types extend
     *
     * @return string The name of the type being extended
     */
    public function getExtendedType()
    {
        return FormType::class;
    }

    /**
     * Add the extra row_attr option
     *
     * @param OptionsResolver $resolver
     */
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'row_attr' => []
        ));
    }

    /**
     * Pass the set row_attr options to the view
     *
     * @param FormView $view
     * @param FormInterface $form
     * @param array $options
     */
    public function buildView(FormView $view, FormInterface $form, array $options)
    {
        $view->vars['row_attr'] = $options['row_attr'];
    }
}
```

Then I registered the service in my bundle...

```
<!-- Form row attributes form extension -->
<service id="acme.form_type_extension" class="Acme\FrontendBundle\Form\Extension\FormTypeExtension">
    <tag name="form.type_extension" alias="form" extended_type="Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\FormType" />
</service>
```

Since every widget extends the base form type this then allows me to pass this new `row_attr` option through on any field, eg:

```
$builder
    ->add('first_name', TextType:class, [
        'row_attr' => [
            'class' => 'form-row-split'
        ]
    ]);
```

Then the twig overrides to make use of the new `row_attr` option:

```
{% block form_row %}
    <div {{ block('form_row_attributes') }}>
        {{ form_label(form) }}
        {{ form_widget(form) }}
        {{ form_errors(form) }}
    </div>
{% endblock form_row %}

{% block form_row_attributes %}
    {% spaceless %}
        {% for attrname, attrvalue in row_attr %}{{ attrname }}="{{ attrvalue }}" {% endfor %}
    {% endspaceless %}
{% endblock form_row_attributes %}
```

And it's done!

(For completeness, my full twig override still merges in the `form-row` and `error` classes in like so:

```
{% set row_attr = row_attr|merge({'class': 'form-row' ~ (row_attr.class is defined ? ' ' ~ row_attr.class : '') ~ (errors|length > 0 ? ' error' : '')} ) %}
```

.. but thats not really necessary for answering my own question :P )

Answer (score 3):

What I did was simpler (though maybe a bit less clean?).

Pass the class for the form row via a field's "data" attribute :

```
// template.html.twig

{{ form_start(form) }}
    {{ form_row(form.field, {'attr': {'data-row-class': 'my-row-class'} }) }}
{{ form_end(form) }}
```

And then handle it in the form theme template this way :

```
// form-theme.html.twig

{% block form_row -%}
    {% set row_class = attr['data-row-class'] | default('') %}
    <div class="{{ row_class }}">
        {{- form_label(form) -}}
        {{- form_widget(form) -}}
        {{- form_errors(form) -}}
    </div>
{%- endblock form_row %}
```

Which gives this :

```
<form name="formName" method="post">
    <div class="my-row-class">
        <label for="formName_field">Field label</label>
        <input type="text" id="formName_field" name="formName[field]" data-row-class="my-row-class">
    </div>
</form>
```