# add class atribute to symfony form builder row div

Tags: css, forms, symfony, attributes, abstract

here is my AbstractType code :

```
   $builder->add('email', 'email', array('label' => 'form.email', 'translation_domain' => 'FOSUserBundle'))
```

code above generated :

```
    <form class="fos_user_registration_register form-horizontal" role="form" method="POST" action="/app_dev.php/register/">

<div id="fos_user_registration_form">
 <div>
   <label class="required" for="fos_user_registration_form_email">Email: </label>
   <input id="fos_user_registration_form_email" type="email" required="required" name="fos_user_registration_form[email]">
 </div>
</div>

</form>
</div>
```

my question is how to add class attribute to the row div become :

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="required" for="fos_user_registration_form_email">Email: </label>
    <input id="fos_user_registration_form_email" type="email" required="required" name="fos_user_registration_form[email]">
</div>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Symfony twig how to add class to a form row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23011450/symfony-twig-how-to-add-class-to-a-form-row)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Symfony2/Twig has a wonderful form rendering engine; it'd be a waste to completely override it. As a much more elegant alternative, we can take advantage of the built-in form themes. As per the documentation:

> Symfony comes with four built-in form themes that define each and every fragment needed to render every part of a form

We can override the default theme and create our own. This allows us to override the `form_row` block, and add our own lovely attributes to the surrounding `div`. Simply put this in a file, say: *views/forms/fields.twig*.

```
{% block form_row %}

    <div class="form-group">
        {{ form_label(form) }}
        {{ form_errors(form) }}
        {{ form_widget(form) }}
    </div>

{% endblock %}
```

We don't need to worry about the other declarations, as Symfony will overload only what's changed.

We can now reference it from the page template. Replace `form` with the name of the form variable passed to the template:

```
{% form_theme form 'forms/fields.twig' %}
```

Of course, you're free to add a declaration to grab a form attribute instead of hard-coding the class name.

(Source: http://symfony.com/doc/2.7/cookbook/form/form_customization.html)

Answer (score 3):

for me the answer of skler is not a solution, because it add the class to the input email, not to the div.

edit:

A better solution

```
{% for child in form.children|keys %}
    <div class="login_field">
        {% if 'token' not in form_label(attribute(form.children,child)) %}
            {{form_label(attribute(form.children,child)) }}
        {% endif %}
        {{form_widget(attribute(form.children,child)) }}
    </div>
    <br/>
{% endfor %}
```

result in:

```
<div class="registration_field">
    <label>e-mail</label>
    <input type="email">
</div>
```

it remove unused div and the token label, and we can use .registration_field selector instead of .registration_field > div

for Amstell:
i answer to the solution of skler, saying that for me it's not a solution,
Sorry, it's not clear.

Comment: When you say, "it's not a solution, because..." then it's not an answer.  Please update if you can help.

Answer (score 2):

Add into your *app/config/config.yml* following lines:

```
twig:
    form:
       resources: ['bootstrap_3_layout.html.twig']
```

or

```
twig:
    form_themes:
        - "bootstrap_3_layout.html.twig"
```

http://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-2-6-bootstrap-form-theme

Answer (score -1):

This question is very similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6734821/how-to-set-a-class-attribute-to-a-symfony2-form-input) other except for the fact that you should use:

```
{{ form_start(form), {'attr': {'class': 'form-group'}} }}
```

Another solution is to define it in Form\Type class:

```
$builder->add('email', 'email', array(
        'label' => 'form.email',
        'translation_domain' => 'FOSUserBundle',
        'attr' => array('class' => 'form-group'),
        'label_attr' => array('class' => 'if-you-want-also-style-attr-label'),
    ));
```

Comment: This will only apply the attribute to the `form` tag. That's not what OP wants.

Comment: Also, you should put the hash inside the form_start declaration, not outside. It won't work otherwise, as that's not valid twig syntax.

Comment: {{ form_start(form), {'attr': {'class': 'form-group'}} }} 
this will produce an error because of " , " the right 
{{ form_start(form, {'attr': {'class': 'form-group'}} )  }}