# In Twig, how to format within rows of form elements, while keeping add/delete working?

Tags: forms, symfony, indexing, twig

On a Symfony project, using Twig for templating, I'm wondering how to control rendering of sub-fields in a set of form elements, while still taking advantage of the Symfony "expand and contract" feature.

Due to business requirements certain elements have to kept together as a set, with multiple inputs per row, and the user being able to add or remove rows as needed.

The Entity object contains:

```
protected $jobInfo = array(array("jobType" => "", "shift" => ""));
```

And the Form object contains :

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $fb, array $options)
{
    //...
    $fb->add('jobInfo', CollectionType::class, array(
        'required' => false,
        'entry_type' => JobSetType::class,
        // ...
        'label' => "bla bla"));
```

The sub-form `JobSetType` simply has two inputs with `ChoiceType::class`. Now if I template it like this in the twig file:

```
{# ... #}
<tr><th>
    {{ form_label(form.jobInfo) }}
</th><td>
    {{ form_widget(form.jobInfo) }}
    {{ form_errors(form.jobInfo) }}
</td></tr>
{# ... #}
```

... then it "works" in the sense that there are more or fewer rows according to how many are in the data, and user can add or delete (with my Javascript). However, the contents of the cell is a jumble of divs, it looks like a mess on the page, and the default labels on the rows are "0", "1", ... which appear as obtuse clutter to the user.

The only way I've found to format the sub-fields, however, is by referring to them with indexes, like this:

```
    <table><tr><th colspan="3">
        {{ form_label(form.jobInfo) }}
    </th></tr>
    {# begin unit intended to repeat #}
    <tr><th>
        {{ form_label(form.jobInfo.0.jobType) }}
    </th><th>
        {{ form_label(form.jobInfo.0.shift) }}
    </th></tr>
    <tr><td>
        {{ form_widget(form.jobInfo.0.jobType) }}
        {{ form_errors(form.jobInfo.0.jobType) }}
    </td><td>
        {{ form_widget(form.jobInfo.0.shift) }}
        {{ form_errors(form.jobInfo.0.shift) }}
    </td></tr>
    {# end unit intended to repeat #}
    </table>
    {{ include('addrow.html.twig', { 'whichRow': 'Another Job' }) }}
```

But now, the use of hardcoded indexes kills the expand-and-contract thing which apparently would have to be simulated by some other means, forfeiting the useful Symfony feature.

Another SO question ([Symfony twig how to add class to a form row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23011450/symfony-twig-how-to-add-class-to-a-form-row)) found that the use of the divs could be changed by changing the master template for form elements, but I don't want that changed for the whole project, just specific templating when needed for individual input sets like this.

How can one control rendering of the sub-elements in this situation, without using hardcoded indexes (or get the same result some other way)?

EDIT: Thanks lordrhodos, I previously tried like this:

```
form_widget(form.jobInfo.{{ loop.index0 }}.shift)
```

and

```
form_widget(form.jobInfo.{{ loop.index }}.shift)
```

with syntax errors on each. My new theory, flip columns and rows.

Comment: You should read the [form theme documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/form/form_themes.html). You can apply them on a per-view basis and do not have to alter a global form theme. I am just wondering ... I think you can loop over `jobInfo` and use the [loop variable](https://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/2.x/tags/for.html) to render the widget and errors.

Answer (score 2):

Solved my own problem.  It just needed a for loop in the twig:

```
        <table>
        <tr><th>
            {{ form_label(form.jobInfo.0.jobType) }}
        </th><th>
            {{ form_label(form.jobInfo.0.shift) }}
        </th></tr>
        {% for x in form.jobInfo %}
            <tr><td>
                {{ form_widget(x.jobType) }}
                {{ form_errors(x.jobType) }}
            </td><td>
                {{ form_widget(x.shift) }}
                {{ form_errors(x.shift) }}
            </td></tr>
        {% endfor %}
        </table>
```